# POSTing JsonObject With HttpClient From Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, asp.net-web-api, wcf-web-api

I'm trying to POST a `JsonObject` using `HttpClient` from Web API. I'm not quite sure how to go about this and can't find much in the way of sample code.

Here's what I have so far:

```
var myObject = (dynamic)new JsonObject();
myObject.Data = "some data";
myObject.Data2 = "some more data";

HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient("myurl");
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

HttpResponseMessage response = httpClient.Post("", ???);
```

I think I need to cast my `JsonObject` as a `StreamContent` but I'm getting hung up on that step.

Comment: Related post - [.NET HttpClient. How to POST string value?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15176538/465053)

Comment: What is this `.Data` property you are using on `JsonObject`?

Answer (score 687, accepted):

With the new version of `HttpClient` and without the `WebApi` package it would be:

```
var content = new StringContent(jsonObject.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
var result = client.PostAsync(url, content).Result;
```

Or if you want it `async`:

```
var result = await client.PostAsync(url, content);
```

Comment: That overloaded StringContent constructor did the trick for me.

Comment: Think twice before calling Result on a Async method though https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html

Comment: For anyone who was tempted to throw this in a `using` like I was: https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/

Comment: I put a `using` around the `StringContent` creation though.

Comment: Using this answer I kept receiving a "400 Bad Request" response from an API I was POSTing my JSON request to (Visual Studio 2017, .NET 4.6.2). In addition to `var content = new StringContent(jsonObject.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")` I had to set `content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");`. See answer below for more details.

Comment: `PostAsJsonAsync` is probably better if available to you - see @user3285954

Comment: The synchronous approach shown above (i.e. using the Result attribute) can also be used for  calls to ReadAsStringAsync e.g. string responseBody = /* await */ response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;   ;)

Comment: There appears to be a 25MB limit. Any ideas ?

Comment: @maxshuty, wrapping HttpClient in a using block would work for cases where you're only ever using it in that block. If you wanted to re-use it or use it to call a different endpoint, it would re-instantiate the HttpClient. Setting it to static would also work for cases where your HttpClient is only ever using one DNS. Depending on the .NET version, you may want to use an IHttpClientFactory for typed Clients and then registering that client as a singleton. Singleton in this case is better than static.

Answer (score 182):

The easiest way is to use a `StringContent`, with the JSON representation of your JSON object.

```
httpClient.Post(
    "",
    new StringContent(
        myObject.ToString(),
        Encoding.UTF8,
        "application/json"));
```

Comment: Take note on the content type. I left it out and had me debugging for much longer than I would like.

Comment: Shouldn't you Dispose the StringContent instance though?

Answer (score 88):

Depending on your .NET version you could also use `HttpClientExtensions.PostAsJsonAsync` method.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclientextensions.postasjsonasync.aspx

Comment: Now found in Microsoft.AspNet.Client.WebApi nuget

Comment: I just installed it from Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client

Comment: This solved my problem. I was messing around for a (long) while passing a C# class that contained some properties that were Lists using client.PostAsync, client.SendAsync.. I was getting very mixed results. If the array was empty my API solution would pick it up, but if the array had an item the controller method was not able to model bind the JSON. Thanks for this.. Seems to me that PostAsJsonAsync more reliably converts a complex C# object to JSON.

Comment: Is there a nuget package for this?  I hate it when I transfer the project to a new machine, and this reference is always missing.

Comment: Looking for this or something else? https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client/

Answer (score 77):

If using Newtonsoft.Json:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;

public static class Extensions
{
    public static StringContent AsJson(this object o)
        => new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(o), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
}
```

Example:

```
var httpClient = new HttpClient();
var url = "https://www.duolingo.com/2016-04-13/login?fields=";
var data = new { identifier = "username", password = "password" };
var result = await httpClient.PostAsync(url, data.AsJson())
```

Comment: this is not asp.net core specific, its actually generic down to even 4.5.6

Comment: `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` issues using ***DateTimes ISO 8601*** Kind: Local or UTC... http://www.hackered.co.uk/articles/useful-c-extensions-for-working-with-iso-8601-dates-and-strings

Comment: @Kiquenet Thank you for this information! I'd been debugging my code for hours. I couldn't find the reason why my post works in Postman and not in my actual C# code.

Answer (score 37):

Using pomber's approach, I kept receiving a "400 Bad Request" response from an API I was POSTing my JSON request to (Visual Studio 2017, .NET 4.6.2). Eventually the problem was traced to the "Content-Type" header produced by StringContent() being incorrect (see https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/7864).

tl;dr

Use pomber's answer with an extra line to correctly set the header on the request:

```
var content = new StringContent(jsonObject.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
var result = client.PostAsync(url, content).Result;
```

Comment: This worked great. Any reason why "application/json" needs to be set twice, one in the constructor and once via the property? Is it a bug?

Comment: @FestusMartingale: good question! From my reading of the github issue (linked in the answer) the passing of `"application/json"` in the `StringContent` constructor is probably not required as it is being explicitly set on the resulting `content.Headers.ContentType` property. However, I haven't tested this in code.

Comment: It looks like the server does not support the full content type string. When you use the constructor without overriding the ContentType, it sets the value as `application/json; charset=utf-8`.

Answer (score 5):

In my case, I am using .NET 7.0; the `StringContent` did not work for me. I adapted some of the answers already provided to my use case. I used `JsonContent` to supply the body for the POST request.

```
var jsonContent = JsonContent.Create(new { ... });
var response = await _client.PostAsync("/", jsonContent);
```

Answer (score 1):

the code over it in vb.net:

```
dim FeToSend as new (object--> define class)

Dim client As New HttpClient
Dim content = New StringContent(FeToSend.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8,"application/json")
content.Headers.ContentType = New MediaTypeHeaderValue( "application/json" )
Dim risp = client.PostAsync(Chiamata, content).Result

msgbox(risp.tostring)
```

Comment: Why would VB.NET code help someone writing ASP.NET code? Please only provide answers to questions using the language(s) specified in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you pomber but for

```
var result = client.PostAsync(url, content).Result;
```

I used

```
var result = await client.PostAsync(url, content);
```

because Result makes app lock for high request

Comment: That is because first example is blocking call, and second works as continuation. [Maybe this explanation helps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13159176/578453)

Answer (score 1):

I Faced same issue i.e

```
var content = new StringContent(jsonObject.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
```

gave

> "400 Bad Request"

Serializing JsonObject separately and passing the string in `StringContent()` solved issue for me, no need to set `Encoding.UTF8` separately.

Answer (score -1):

I want to answer all in one response when doing this job as a note for all and myself:

According to Serez's answer HttpContent derived classes list as below
https://stackoverflow.com/a/42380027/914284

HttpClient PostAsync has some background depending on the context you working on!

- You can post data by the type that you want to send to server in cases
  Server context waits it as bellow

> ```
>     [HttpPost]
>     public async Task<IActionResult> Submit(MyModel model)
>     [HttpPost]
>     public async Task<IActionResult> Submit([FromForm] MyModel model)
>     [HttpPost]
>     public async Task<IActionResult> Submit([FromBody] MyModel model)
> ```

When writing FromForm or Body it has working as FromForm.
FromBody needs json content otherwise it requires KeyValuePairs as rows. There is some implementations for both of them such as below:

For **FromForm**: I have used an extension

```
public static class HelperExtensions
    {
        public static FormUrlEncodedContent ToFormData(this object obj)
        {
            var formData = obj.ToKeyValue();

            return new FormUrlEncodedContent(formData);
        }

        public static IDictionary<string, string> ToKeyValue(this object metaToken)
        {
            if (metaToken == null)
            {
                return null;
            }

            // Added by me: avoid cyclic references
            var serializer = new JsonSerializer { ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore };
            if (metaToken is not JToken token)
            {
                // Modified by me: use serializer defined above
                return ToKeyValue(JObject.FromObject(metaToken, serializer));
            }

            if (token.HasValues)
            {
                var contentData = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                foreach (var child in token.Children().ToList())
                {
                    var childContent = child.ToKeyValue();
                    if (childContent != null)
                    {
                        contentData = contentData.Concat(childContent)
                                                 .ToDictionary(k => k.Key, v => v.Value);
                    }
                }

                return contentData;
            }

            var jValue = token as JValue;
            if (jValue?.Value == null)
            {
                return null;
            }

            var value = jValue?.Type == JTokenType.Date ?
                            jValue?.ToString("o", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) :
                            jValue?.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

            return new Dictionary<string, string> { { token.Path, value } };
        }
    }
```

For **FromBody**: Use any json converter library Newtonsoft or microsoft

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

var jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
```

In both of them, content type should be defined according the requirement, for example for json (Write to header)

```
request.Headers.Accept.Clear();
request.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
```

or another usage

```
        using (var content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(answer), System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"))
        {
            var answerResponse = await client.PostAsync(url, content);
            //use await it has moved in some context on .core 6.0
        }
```

If you should use authorization on the context also you can provide authorization as below:

```
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", "Your Oauth token");
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead, do this:

```
var content = new StringContent(jsonObject.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

var result = client.PostAsync(url, content).Result;
```

This is what I am using. It's safer

```
JsonContent content = JsonContent.Create(ObjectData);

HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(url, content);
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?

Comment: Please elaborate how exactly your solution works and solves the issue.