# .NET HttpClient. How to POST string value?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, dotnet-httpclient

How can I create using C# and HttpClient the following POST request:
[image: User-Agent: Fiddler Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded Host: localhost:6740 Content-Length: 6]

I need such a request for my WEB API service:

```
[ActionName("exist")]
[HttpPost]
public bool CheckIfUserExist([FromBody] string login)
{           
    return _membershipProvider.CheckIfExist(login);
}
```

Comment: What HTTP client are you using in the image?

Comment: http://www.telerik.com/fiddler

Comment: The service is Web Api MVC. ***JSON format*** for request?

Comment: Related post - [POSTing JsonObject With HttpClient From Web API](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6117101/465053)

Answer (score 496, accepted):

In ASP.NET 4.5 (for 4.0, you need to install the [`Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client`](http://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client/) NuGet package):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net.Http;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Task.Run(() => MainAsync());
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static async Task MainAsync()
    {
        var client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:6740");
        var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
        {
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("", "login")
        });
        var result = await client.PostAsync("/api/Membership/exists", content);
        string resultContent = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        Console.WriteLine(resultContent);
    }
}
```

Comment: Result is ***UrlEncoded Content***, not ***JSON format*** for request?

Comment: what if I wanted to use `new KeyValuePair<string, string>("", "login" + someOtherString)`

Answer (score 42):

Below is example to call synchronously but you can easily change to async by using await-sync:

```
var pairs = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
            {
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("login", "abc")
            };

var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(pairs);

var client = new HttpClient {BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:6740")};

    // call sync
var response = client.PostAsync("/api/membership/exist", content).Result; 
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
}
```

Comment: I don't think this will work. you should replace "login" with empty string, it should be KeyValuePair<string, string>("", "abc"), see the accepted answer.

Comment: this works for me, work on php webservice that is calling $company_id = $_POST("company_id"); like that. If I send as json, php cannot work.

Answer (score 31):

[Here](http://zetcode.com/csharp/httpclient/) I found this article which is send post request using `JsonConvert.SerializeObject()` & `StringContent()` to `HttpClient.PostAsync` data

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    var person = new Person();
    person.Name = "John Doe";
    person.Occupation = "gardener";

    var json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(person);
    var data = new System.Net.Http.StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

    var url = "https://httpbin.org/post";
    using var client = new HttpClient();

    var response = await client.PostAsync(url, data);

    string result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Here is a small part from the POST section of [How to call an api with asp.net](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client):

> The following code sends a POST request that contains a Product instance in JSON format:
>
> ```
> // HTTP POST
> var gizmo = new Product() { Name = "Gizmo", Price = 100, Category = "Widget" };
> response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/products", gizmo);
> if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
> {
>     // Get the URI of the created resource.
>     Uri gizmoUrl = response.Headers.Location;
> }
> ```

Comment: The request is form-urlencoded so I don't think JSON will work

Comment: It's *form-urlencoded*. Anyways, ***JSON format*** for `DateTime` properties? serialization issues?

Comment: I don't seem to notice your method "PostAsJsonAsync" It is not available in my HttpClient instance.

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this

```
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:6740/api/Membership/exist");

req.Method = "POST";
req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";         
req.ContentLength = 6;

StreamWriter streamOut = new StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream(), System.Text.Encoding.ASCII);
streamOut.Write(strRequest);
streamOut.Close();
StreamReader streamIn = new StreamReader(req.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
string strResponse = streamIn.ReadToEnd();
streamIn.Close();
```

And then strReponse should contain the values returned by your webservice

Comment: The question here was about how to use the new `HttpClient` and not the old `WebRequest`.

Comment: True I didn't noticed, i'll leave the post anyway in case someone needs the old one...