# Make HTML request with this header

Tags: post, windows-store-apps, dotnet-httpclient

[image]

My code is:

```
var client = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri("http://bf4stats.com") };
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Referer", ":http://bf4stats.com/pc/Azezeil");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-Requested-With", ": XMLHttpRequest");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsync("/pc/Azezeil", new StringContent("{" + "\"" + "request" + "\"" + ":" + "\"" + "updatePlayer" + "\"" + "}", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")).Result;
        string res = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

The response come failed 417.
How to make a POST request with HttpClient or any thing works on Windows Store apps C#?

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5401501/how-to-post-data-to-specific-url-using-webclient-in-c-sharp

Comment: This link for PHP not C#.

Comment: The link is for C#. What makes you think it isn't?

Comment: Sorry my mistake. WebClient seems doesn't supported on windows store apps.

Comment: What about this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15176538/net-httpclient-how-to-post-string-value

Comment: Don't delete your question, some others may run into this issue.

Comment: Do you mean HTTP request? Please could you update your question, and add your language as a tag - thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error 417 is "Expectation Failed".  This is because, when you do a POST, by default HttpClient will send a Expect Continue header and wait for a 100 response before continuing with the POST.  To disable this behavior, you can do,

```
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.ExpectContinue = false;
```