# Application login to website failed

Tags: c#, winforms, cookies, authentication, httpwebrequest

My goal is to login at http://uk.advfn.com using my application, I am novice in C#, I learnt about the below code from another link, but I cannot manage to work out mine. When I debug, the `response` shows bad login page rather than login successful page. Can anyone kind to look into it for me where did I do wrongly?

I use Tamper Data firefox addon to obtain those needed values, but I am not sure if I use them correctly.

Your help is very much appreciated! Thank you. :)

Part 1:

```
        public class CookieAwareWebClient : WebClient
    {
        public string Method;
        public CookieContainer CookieContainer { get; set; }
        public Uri Uri { get; set; }

        public CookieAwareWebClient()
            : this(new CookieContainer())
        {
        }

        public CookieAwareWebClient(CookieContainer cookies)
        {
            this.CookieContainer = cookies;
        }

        protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
        {
            WebRequest request = base.GetWebRequest(address);
            if (request is HttpWebRequest)
            {
                (request as HttpWebRequest).CookieContainer = this.CookieContainer;
                (request as HttpWebRequest).ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = false;
                (request as HttpWebRequest).UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:26.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/26.0";
                (request as HttpWebRequest).Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
                (request as HttpWebRequest).Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptLanguage, "en-US,en;q=0.5");
                (request as HttpWebRequest).Referer = "http://uk.advfn.com/";
                (request as HttpWebRequest).KeepAlive = true;
                (request as HttpWebRequest).AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.Deflate | DecompressionMethods.GZip;
                if (Method == "POST")
                {
                    (request as HttpWebRequest).ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
                }

            }
            HttpWebRequest httpRequest = (HttpWebRequest)request;
            httpRequest.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;
            return httpRequest;
        }

        protected override WebResponse GetWebResponse(WebRequest request)
        {
            WebResponse response = base.GetWebResponse(request);
            String setCookieHeader = response.Headers[HttpResponseHeader.SetCookie];

            if (setCookieHeader != null)
            {
                //do something if needed to parse out the cookie.
                try
                {
                    if (setCookieHeader != null)
                    {
                        Cookie cookie = new Cookie(); //create cookie
                        this.CookieContainer.Add(cookie);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {

                }
            }
            return response;
        }
    }
```

Part 2:

```
        private void btn_login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var cookieJar = new CookieContainer();
        CookieAwareWebClient client = new CookieAwareWebClient(cookieJar);
        string response = client.DownloadString("http://uk.advfn.com/common/account/login");
        string postData = string.Format("redirect_url=aHR0cDovL3VrLmFkdmZuLmNvbQ%3D%3D&site=uk&login_username=demouser&login_password=demopassword");
        client.Method = "POST";
        response = client.UploadString("https://secure.advfn.com/login/secure", postData);
    }
```

Comment: did you provide correct cookies in your cookie container to login?

Comment: Are you sure your username and password that you are using are correct?

Comment: Can you use .net 4.5? Maybe HttpClinet is easier to use: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15176538/net-httpclient-how-to-post-string-value

Comment: Maybe using Selenium WebDriver for Firefox can solve your problem? I can provide example if you are interested. Your app would need to open an instance of Firefox. http://docs.seleniumhq.org/

Comment: 1. First you set the response variable to "http://uk.advfn.com/common/account/login", but you do not use it. you only set it to another value on the last line.

2. The URL: https://secure.advfn.com/login/secure does not exist.

3. If i try to login using a browser with "demouser" and the password "demopassword" i get an invalid login message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought I would just put an update to my own question, so that it might be able to help out others.

I ended up skip all the complicated code, I used Selenium to login the website, then download the files that I needed. Selenium is indeed a powerful tool, I downloaded 900+ files using a certain interval in each download, by just using Selenium and Firefox. Special thanks to @VDohnal who left a comment to me, unfortunately I can only upvote his comment since there's no "answer" from him.

The code is exported from Selenium IDE, I altered the code a bit and added the part where I need to do my downloads.

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading;
using NUnit.Framework;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;

namespace SeleniumTests
{
    private IWebDriver driver;
    private StringBuilder verificationErrors;
    private string baseURL;
    private bool acceptNextAlert = true;

    private bool IsElementPresent(By by)
    {
        try
        {
            driver.FindElement(by);
            return true;
        }
        catch (NoSuchElementException)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    private bool IsAlertPresent()
    {
        try
        {
            driver.SwitchTo().Alert();
            return true;
        }
        catch (NoAlertPresentException)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    private string CloseAlertAndGetItsText()
    {
        try
        {
            IAlert alert = driver.SwitchTo().Alert();
            string alertText = alert.Text;
            if (acceptNextAlert)
            {
                alert.Accept();
            }
            else
            {
                alert.Dismiss();
            }
            return alertText;
        }
        finally
        {
            acceptNextAlert = true;
        }
    }

    public void TheCTest()
    {
        try
        {
            driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            baseURL = "http://uk.advfn.com";
            verificationErrors = new StringBuilder();
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(baseURL + "/common/account/login");
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("login_username")).Clear();
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("login_username")).SendKeys("demouser");
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("login_password")).Clear();
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("login_password")).SendKeys("demopass");
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("login_submit")).Click();
            Thread.Sleep(30000);
            //driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView_FetchTickers.Rows)
            {
                if (row.Cells[1].Value != null)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(baseURL + "/p.php?pid=data&daily=0&symbol=L%5E" + row.Cells[1].Value.ToString());
                        //driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));
                        Thread.Sleep(30000);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                    }

                }
                else
                {
                    //Do nothing
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            //
        }  
    }

    private void btn_fetchSharePrices_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TheCTest();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use fiddler to capture the http request of a successful login done through the browser and then compare that to the request generated by the application. Any discrepancies in the two may hold clues as to why the application is unable to login successfully.

Answer (score 1):

I did some remote login to a website a few years ago and I have saved the StackOverflow Question that helped me.

[Login to website, via C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/930807/c-sharp-login-to-website-via-program)

I couldn't find my code because I'm not working at the same company I used to but hope this helps...

Answer (score 1):

I've tried your code and it works fine. The only thing i had to do is to change password and login to correct one.

I guess the reason you have 'bad logon' message is because you actually entered bad login and password.

Comment: Hi Pavel, thank you for your reply. I did use correct username and password. I've tried it out through web browser before I use my application to do the login task. Did you use exactly what my code is? I'll be trying everyone's solutions/suggestions within 22 hours from now, so that I can reward the right one. Thank you. :)

Comment: I used just the same code as listed in your message.

Comment: I've inserted it into linqPad, changed login:pass and pressed run =)

Once there was a strange case in my practise, witch was related that authentification cookie was returned not in response, but in request. But i dont think that it is your case.

There was good advice given to you upper, use fiddler to compare requests from browser and from your application. Some times even 1 byte matters.

There not much help I can give you becouse there is no way to reproduce this behavior on my machine.