# Get token from Web API 2 and Windows Store Apps

Tags: c#

I try to do something really simple but I can't find the way to achieve my goal.

So I have a WEB API (C#) and inside I use Oauth 2 token.  So I want my windows store apps to get the access token but no matters what I tried I always get http 400.

I know the Web API is fine because I have a angular.js application and I always get the token and I try to with the Chrome Plugin Postman and it's fine too so I guess I don't know the good parameters.

I use HttpClient and my windows store apps it's a windows store apps 8.1.

The uri of the token is like http://localhost:5252/token

Thanks

Comment: Run [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) and see if the request/response is correct. Might give you a clue as to what's wrong.

Comment: Okay I found it finally 

Here the solution : 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15176538/net-httpclient-how-to-post-string-value