# HTTP Post from c#.net

Tags: c#, http-post, form-post

Our third party payment gateway provider only supports the FORM POST for handshake, payment and payment verification etc.

For this we need to perform a POST from C#.NET. Could someone help me whether there's any NUGET Packages or samples to achieve this?

I had a look at [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debx8sh9%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) already but did not find elegant:

Comment: What is the problem with the solution described in the MSDN-article?

Comment: @stefankmitph He actually asks for a different solution.

Comment: @PatrikEckebrecht yeah, and the duplicate question with the highest rated answer offers 3 different solutions.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15176538/net-httpclient-how-to-post-string-value

Answer (score 1):

One easy way is to use [RestSharp](http://restsharp.org/).

This is a sample POST request.

```
using RestSharp;

var client = new RestClient("http://example.com");
// client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator(username, password);

var request = new RestRequest("resource/{id}", Method.POST);
request.AddParameter("name", "value"); 
request.AddUrlSegment("id", "123"); 
// easily add HTTP Headers
request.AddHeader("header", "value");

// add files to upload (works with compatible verbs)
request.AddFile(path);

// execute the request
RestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

Comment: Per my post, it's not a REST or SOAP service. It's just aspx page which accepts form post. For initial hand shake we need to post data via code.