# Why is System.Net.Http HttpClient encoding my request URL?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, dotnet-httpclient, system.net.httpwebrequest

I use the HttpClient in System.Net.Http to make requests to a web service as below:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    using (var response = client.GetAsync(url).Result)
    {
        var result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    }
}
```

I have a sandbox application and a live application. The sandbox application has identical code (in a shared repository) which works fine, but when `client.GetAsync(url).Result` is called in the live application, for some reason Fiddler shows me that the requested URL has been encoded which messes the request up.

Requested URL is supposed to look like this:

```
/advert?paginate=1&page=1&language=en&filters[updated_at][ge]=2016-03-21%2012:19:05
```

But ends up looking like this:

```
/advert?paginate=1&page=1&language=en&filters%5Bupdated_at%5D%5Bge%5D=2016-03-21%2012:19:05
```

Any idea why? Thanks

**N.B. Im using the Microsoft.Net.Http library from Nuget in .NET Framework 4.5**

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding

Comment: That second URL is a perfectly legitimate way to represent the first one. It sounds like, if anything, the service receiving the request has a problem with properly encoded URLs.

Comment: @CSharpie: I understand the point of URL encoding, but the unexpected encoding of (specifically) the square brackets is where I am confused. Specially because the same code works differently in another project.

Comment: @JLRishe: Unforunately, the service responds fine to the first request, but gives "no results" to the second. Which i assume is to do with the way their application parses search parameters from the URL.

Comment: Have you tried adding the post parameters like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15176632/1789202) answer suggests?

Comment: @CSharpie: The web service specifically wants a GET in this case, and I dont think a `GetAsync` will accept parameters in the same way that a `PostAsync` will. I was hopeful though!

Comment: You really should not be doing `.Result`, you really should switch the code to async/await or use `WebClient` instead of `HttpClient` which has synchronous methods.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: Appreciated. This is being used here as an example of case in point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Please be very specific about your question:

   - you use Microsoft.Net.Http version what?
   - you compile under .NET version what?
2. Turned out that you compile under .NET 4.0 and this is a bug I would say, because the behavior is not identical to the .NET Fx 4.5 System.Http

You can fix it by setting `dontEscape` to true in the Uri class:

```
 var url = new Uri(@"http://google.com/advert?paginate=1&page=1&language=en&filters[updated_at][ge]=2016-03-21%2012:19:05", dontEscape: true);
```

Comment: 'dontEscape' is now obsolete

Comment: @Lance can you confirm that this is not an issue with the latest .NET FX / Core?

Comment: Looks like it is still obsolete in Core 3.1 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri.-ctor?view=netcore-3.1#System_Uri__ctor_System_String_System_Boolean_