# How to make a method asynchronous when I need to wait for an event

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task, httprequest

I made a function like this:

```
public void GetData(string dataToPost)
{
    var url = "some URL";

    using (var client = new WebClient())
    {
        client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/json";

        client.UploadStringCompleted += (s, e) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Result is here");
                Console.WriteLine(e.Result);
            };

        client.UploadStringAsync(new System.Uri(url), "POST", dataToPost);
    }
}
```

The problem here is the fact that I want to get a value returned from the server (HTTP response).

I want my function to be asynchronous, so for example I'd like to be able to call it 5 times in a loop, without waiting for each call to return something before next call.

I have no idea how to achieve it. I tried to create some Task object to await it, but Task requires a delegate and I don't know what delegate i could give it.

Te function above uses an event, which is fired when the result comes - so I need to return that result.

How can I do that?

Comment: It's a console app. I'm quite new to all this, so I'm not sure if I understand what you mean. UploadStringAsync  returns void. //edit Looks like someone deleted his comment

Comment: Sorry, I thought you were using `HttpClient`. You need to subscribe to the `UploadStringCompleted` event which will be called once the call completes.

Comment: Would it be possible to switch to `HttpClient` as this has native async/await support, like https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh138242.aspx.

Comment: @Igor, it doesn't matter for me, if you know a way to do it with HttpClient, I can use it

Comment: In that case see this previous question/answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15176685/1260204

Comment: Thanks, HttpClient seems to be a better option. But, just out of curiosity, is it possible to do what i was asking for? Is it an option to make my method asynchronous (it would return Task<string>)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`WebClient` has an overload that returns a `Task<string>`:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh193920(v=vs.110).aspx

You can fire all your requests and then wait for them with `Task.WhenAll`:

```
public void GetData(string dataToPost)
{
    var url = "some URL";
    var url2 = "some other URL";

    using (var client = new WebClient())
    {
        client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/json";

        var task1 = client.UploadStringTaskAsync(new System.Uri(url), "POST", dataToPost);
        var task2 = client.UploadStringTaskAsync(new System.Uri(url2), "POST", dataToPost);

        var results = Task.WhenAll(task1, task2).Result;

        foreach (var result in results)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Result is here");
            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }
    }
}
```

Even better if you can change your GetData to be an `async` method, you can just `await` on `Task.WhenAll`

Answer (score 1):

As already been said in comments, `HttpClient` is more natural choice for such tasks. However, you still may wonder how to provide a task subscribed for an event, and that could be done with [`TaskCompletionSource<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd449174.aspx), with quite small changes to your code:

```
private Task<string> GetData(string dataToPost)
{
    var url = "some URL";
    var resultSource = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();

    using (var client = new WebClient())
    {
        client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/json";

        client.UploadStringCompleted += (s, e) => {
            Console.WriteLine("Result is here");
            Console.WriteLine(e.Result);

            // this will complete the task
            resultSource.SetResult(e.Result);
        };

        client.UploadStringAsync(new System.Uri(url), "POST", dataToPost);
    }

    return resultSource.Task;
}
```

You can also set a [cancellation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd449205.aspx) (with a [given token](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn823326.aspx) too) and [exception](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd449204.aspx) (even with [multiple exceptions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783450.aspx)) in this case, so it will naturally fit to your needs. All three methods can be done in `Try*` fashion for the cases of concurrent event subscription.

Also note the @Stefanod'Antonio' answer for an [`async` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh193920.aspx) overload.

Comment: Thanks for your input, that's interesting. Looks to me like a Promise of JavaScript.

Comment: `Task` in C# and `Promise` in Javascript are nearly equivalent.