# ServiceStack client post body

Tags: asp.net, rest, servicestack

I run a local ServiceStack service by using the template from the docs.

I'd like to be able to POST information. Get works fine, but I need it to be able to POST data including a body. I test this using postman, which works fine as well. The data contained in the body consists of two key-value pairs (string).

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15176538/net-httpclient-how-to-post-string-value) describes the problem I have, but with HTTPClient instead of ServiceStack. The following snippet shows the method I use for my GET request.

```
var client = new JsonServiceClient("http://192.168.0.5:12345/hello");
try
{
    HelloResponse response = await client.GetAsync(new Hello{ Name = Username ?? "" });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to send a HTTP POST request instead of a GET Request, you'd just use the `Post` API, e.g:

```
await client.PostAsync(requestDto)
```

If you want to send a raw POST body in addition to Request DTO properties your Request DTO needs to implement `IRequiresRequestStream` then you can use the `PostBody` API, see the [ServiceStack docs for details](http://docs.servicestack.net/csharp-client#sending-typed-request-with-raw-body).