# HttpClient won't work

Tags: c#, asynchronous, xamarin.android, async-await, httpclient

So I'm trying to send a multiform POST to API with http client but it's just hang there indefinetly. I test this code in console and it worked as it should, but then I try to run it like this for the UI

```
private static async Task<string> ApiTask(...)
{
    var SourceStream = File.Open(imgpath,FileMode.Open);
    var FileStreamContent = new StreamContent(SourceStream);
    FileStreamContent.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("image/jpeg");
    var client = new HttpClient();
    using (var formData = new MultipartFormDataContent())
    {
        formData.Add(new StringContent("this is a test"),"comment");
        formData.Add(new StringContent("Command: detect"),"message");
        formData.Add(fileStreamContent, "image","image.jpg");
        var response = await client.PostAsync(url,formData).ConfigureAwait(false);
        var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        return responseString
    }
}
```

And I'm calling it from the  EventHandler

```
public async void buttnclck(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var task = await ApiTask(...);
    lblresult.Text = task;
}
```

but as I said the code just stay in de `.PostAsync` line indefinetly or when a System.Threading.Task.TaskCanceledException is thrown.

So what I missing here? I thing I was handeling the async/await methods just fine but it's clear I'm not. I tried also with `.Result` but it won't work even and would throw System.AggregateException. So please help, been trying to make it work modifying the code as other suggested responses but still not working

EDIT:
after couple of hours debugging and searching I find out my problem relies in `formData.Add(FileStreamContent, "image","image.jpg");` maybe I'm not serializing the image correctly? How can I fix this??

Comment: Make your life easier - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15176538/net-httpclient-how-to-post-string-value

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.NET HttpClient. How to POST string value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15176538/net-httpclient-how-to-post-string-value)

Comment: @SeanMitchell already tried that and didn't work

Comment: Have you tried using Fiddler to see what goes on the wire?

Comment: @PauloMorgado not fiddler but postman. I find out my problem was at sending the image to the server and I need to figure it out how to send it the right way

Comment: How did you use Postman to see what the HttpClient was sending and receiving?

Comment: @PauloMorgado I don't, emulator has been buggy lately and fiddler doesn't catch my andorid device by usb. I used postman just to check if the server where running fine and it did. I'm pretty sure my problem relies in not been able to sent the image on the body of the post

Comment: So, this is, definitely, not a `visual-studio` problem. It might be a `xamarin android` problem.