# How to call POST method from API using HttpClient?

Tags: c#, rest, httpcontent

I am trying to use the HttpClient class to call a POST method from my API which is supposed to add Server information to a DB.

The way I'm trying to call it is below. But when I step through it to debug it steps through my if statement for response.IsSuccessStatusCode.

```
public static async Task<Server> PostServer(Server server)
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:50489/");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            StringContent content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(server));
            // HTTP POST
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync("api/Server/", content);
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                string data = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                server = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Server>(data);
            }
        }
        return server;
    }
```

Also here is the POST method in my API below it was automatically generated in VS.

```
// POST: api/Servers
    [ResponseType(typeof(Server))]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostServer(Server server)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        db.Servers.Add(server);
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();

        return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = server.Server_ID }, server);
    }
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to post data using HttpClient?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20005355/how-to-post-data-using-httpclient)

Comment: Use a tool like Fiddler to see what is actually being returned by your API. Sounds like it's returning an error. Without more information it's impossible to tell what's going on here.

Comment: Try adding the `[HttpPost]` attribute to the action on your server. Without it you're probably getting a 404.

Comment: It would be interesting to know what the status code is, it's usually quite clear what the problem is. How did you encode your data? Accept Header refers just one media. I see that is a localserver, but is it accepting that format? The size of the POST data is usually necessary too.