# Request.Form returns empty data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am working with two APIs. One is sending data and another one is receiving data, then do some work with it. Here is the code:

Sender API:

```
var campaignId = "1234";  
if (campaignId != null)
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        var httpContent = new StringContent(
            JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
                new { CampaignId = campaignId }),
            Encoding.UTF8,
            "application/json");  //also tried with application/x-www-form-urlencoded
            var uri = new StringBuilder(_domain)
                .Append("/api/mailchimp/campaign/send");
            var response = await client.PostAsync(uri.ToString(), httpContent);  
            ....  
            ....  
    }  
}
```

Receiver API:

```
var campaignId = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["CampaignId"];  //also tried with Request.Params["CampaignId"] but here the Request.Form is always null
```

This technique always works for me when I serialize an object and then send it to the receiver API. But here there is only 1 variable (campaignId) so I don't want to use any model. Is there anything wrong with this syntax?

Comment: You're posting JSON. That's not a form.

Comment: If you're using ASP.NET MVC, why are you using Request.Form? Why aren't you using the model binding?

Comment: @CodeCaster yes also tried with application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Comment: @mason i dont want to create a separate class for only 1 variable. I already have a lot of models. So I was thinking maybe I could do an exception this time.

Comment: for literally a single variable you don't need a whole new model, but your action method can still just accept `int parameterID` directly as an input parameter and MVC will do the rest, without having to look in the Request object directly.

Comment: You also can't post JSON as a form. That's still not a form.

Comment: ok so I need to use KeyValuePair. thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Why do you think you need a KeyValuePair?

Comment: to use FormUrlEncodedContent(). see suggested duplicate question: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20005355/how-to-post-data-using-httpclient