# .NET Core Web API parameter binding issue [FromForm] and [FromBody]

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> Register([FromForm] RegisterViewModel model)
{

}
```

This is a web controller action and I am passing it a model from another simple controller:

```cs
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/Account/Register", model);
```

The issue is that the model (`RegisterViewModel`) contains an `IFormFile` type field and to send that along, I have to use `[FromForm]`, but it only work if data directly submitted from form to api but i am submitting form to a simple controller and the submitting it to api using HttpClient and if I use `[FromBody]` it accepts all other fields but it won't accept `IFormFile` field

```cs
    public class RegisterViewModel
    {
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Email")]
        [EmailAddress]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Password")]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
        [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Enter First Name:")]
        [StringLength(maximumLength: 30, MinimumLength = 3)]
        [MaxLength(30)]
        [Display(Name = "First Name")]
        public string firstName { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Enter Last Name:")]
        [StringLength(maximumLength: 30, MinimumLength = 3)]
        [MaxLength(30)]
        [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
        public string lastName { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Select Profile Picture")]
        public IFormFile profilePicture { get; set; }
        public string profilePictureName { get; set; }

        [StringLength(200)]
        [MaxLength(200)]
        [Display(Name = "Add Facebook Link To Your Profile")]
        [DataType(DataType.Url)]
        public string facebookLink { get; set; }

        [StringLength(200)]
        [MaxLength(200)]
        [Display(Name = "Add Instagram Link To Your Profile")]
        [DataType(DataType.Url)]
        public string instagramLink { get; set; }

        [StringLength(200)]
        [MaxLength(200)]
        [Display(Name = "Add Twitter Link To Your Profile")]
        [DataType(DataType.Url)]
        public string twitterLink { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Enter Date Of Birth:")]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime DOB { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Registration No")]
        public string season { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string department { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string roll { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> seasons { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> departments { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: can you post your viewmodel?

Comment: @ArvindMaurya i edited the question you can check.

Comment: You can use file as base64 string to save in api, if you are calling it from C#

Comment: That's a one way but i am looking for if it can be send as IformFile

Comment: No, you can't. There's is not JSON rappresentation for IFormFile, and it is not serializable/deserializable in JSON. @BambamDeo is right, if your WebApi is to be called passing json content, files must be passed as base64 strings.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do it through attribute binding, but it is definitely possible. An example of how to accomplish this is on [microsoft's docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-3.1#code-try-14)

Comment: try put in form tage ```enctype="multipart/form-data"```

Comment: you can't mix json and formdata. choose one, either pass everything as form data or use base64 file data in json.

Comment: @alim91 that's what i'm trying to do i set the call type to multipart/form-data 
```client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("multipart/form-data"));```but how to set content type for HttpClient i search alot but didn't find. Is there any way you know?

Comment: @MarkusDresch yes i want to post everything as form data but how to do this i think i have to set some property of HttpClient if you know?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20005355/how-to-post-data-using-httpclient

Comment: @MarkusDresch if you are suggestiong `FormUrlEncodedContent` first it's not binding a single value to model and 2nd it only accept a <string,string> key value pair and i want to send IFormFile

Comment: @MarkusDresch i found a way i posted the answer in case you wanted to check

Comment: @ClaudioValerio i found a way i posted the answer in case you want to check

Comment: @peinearydevelopment  i found a way i posted the answer in case you want to check