# HttpClient Post Async call

Tags: c#, .net, rest, odata, ptc-windchill

I am trying to call a Windchill Odata rest service. THE HTTP GET method works fine, but it is not working as expected when making a POST request. I am also not sure how to pass the required parameter to the URL. Any suggestions will help a lot.

URL that I am trying to call

```
http://Hostname/Windchill/servlet/odata/v3/ProdMgmt/Parts('OR:wt.part.WTPart:123456')/PTC.ProdMgmt.GetPartStructure?$expand=Components($select=PartName,PartNumber;$expand=PartUse($select=FindNumber,LineNumber,Quantity,Unit);$levels=1)
```

Parameter that need to be passed to the URL is ('OR:wt.part.WTPart:123456'). I am doing this in C# .NET.

My C# code

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
 {
  client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new 
 MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

  var byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("abc:defg!");

  client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray));

  client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("CSRF_NONCE", a.NonceValue);

   var message = await client.PostAsync("hostname/Windchill/servlet/odata/v3/ProdMgmt/Parts('OR:wt.part.WTPart:123456')/PTC.ProdMgmt.GetPartStructure?$expand=Components($select=PartName,PartNumber;$expand=PartUse($select=FindNumber,LineNumber,Quantity,Unit);$levels=1)", null);
  }
```

Any example or sample code is much appreciated.

Comment: Where is your C# code?

Comment: Hi
I have added the C# code to my question. Thank you for checking my question. Any help is appreciated

Comment: How specifically does the code fail?  How have you confirmed that it's failing here and not on the server?

Comment: When you POST data, you will usually need to put the data in the HTTP body, not in the querystring as you are doing. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20005355/how-to-post-data-using-httpclient)

Comment: duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015324/how-to-make-an-http-post-web-request

Comment: @JohnWu I tried it the below way but getting Status Code: 406 - 'Not Acceptable' error
 var formContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
                       {
                                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("PartId", "OR:wt.part.WTPart:4143527554")
                        });


                        HttpResponseMessage message = await client.PostAsync("v3/ProdMgmt/Parts('{PartId}')/PTC.ProdMgmt.GetPartStructure", formContent);

Comment: You will need to talk to the people who run that service, or read their documentation.  Sounds like you aren't sending data the way they expect, but there is no way I can tell you what they are expecting.