# Connecting to PHP api from c# project

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-web-api, postman

I have an api

```
http://cbastest.cadvilpos.com/module/posmodule/customapi
```

with parameters

```
{
    "action":4,
    "device_token": "3e8ea119a90ee6d2",
    "key":"9475962085b3a1b8c475d52.95782804",
    "shop":1,
    "language":1
  }
```

This is working fine in postman. But when I try to connect from c# project its showing an error `{"success":0,"error":"Missing the action parameter."}`. Please give a working C# code to get the json result.

The code I tried:

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://cbastest.cadvilpos.com/module/posmodule/customapi");
var postData = "{ 'action':'4', 'device_token':'3e8ea119a90ee6d2','key':'9475962085b3a1b8c475d52.95782804','shop':'1','language':'1'}";
var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);

request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/json";
request.ContentLength = data.Length;

using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
{
    stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
}

var response2 = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
var responseString = new StreamReader(response2.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
```

Comment: Can you share us how is the code of your C# Action?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [POSTing JsonObject With HttpClient From Web API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6117101/posting-jsonobject-with-httpclient-from-web-api)

Comment: You *don't* need to use a raw HttpWebRequest object to make an HTTP call. Check the duplicate, it only takes 2 lines to call `var content=new StringContent(postData,Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");var response=await httpClient.PostAsync(url,content);`. 3 lines if you *don't* construct the JSON string by hand but use eg JSON.NET to serialize a strongly typed object.

Comment: And only one line if you use the `PostAsJsonAsync` extension method found in [Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client/). Never mind the name, the package adds formatting methods on top of HttpClient. It's not specific to ASP.NET Web API

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use a raw HttpWebRequest object to make an HTTP call. [HttpClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.110).aspx) was introduced in 2012 to allow easy asynchronous HTTP calls.

You could do something as simple as :

```
var content=new StringContent(postData,Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
HttpResponseMessage response=await httpClient.PostAsync(url,content);
//Now process the response
if (response.IsSuccessCode)
{
   var body=await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
   var responseDTO=JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyDTO>(body);
}
```

Instead of building a JSON string by hand you could use a strongly typed class or an anonymous object and serialize it to JSON with JSON.NET :

```
var data=new {
    action=4,
    device_token="3e8ea119a90ee6d2",
    key = "9475962085b3a1b8c475d52.95782804",
    shop=1,
    language=1
};

var postData=JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
var content=new StringContent(postData,Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
var response=await httpClient.PostAsync(url,content);
...
```

You can read a response body in one go as a string, using [ReadAsStringAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpcontent.readasstringasync%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) or you can get the response stream with [ReadAsStreamAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpcontent.readasstreamasync(v=vs.110).aspx). You could copy the response data directly to another stream, eg a file or memory stream with [HttpContent.CopyToAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh138076(v=vs.110).aspx)

Check [Call a Web API from a .NET Client](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client#install-the-web-api-client-libraries) for more examples. Despite the title, the examples work to call any HTTP/REST API.

The `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client` package mentioned in that article is another thing that applies to any call, not just calls to ASP.NET Web API. The extension method `PostAsJsonAsync` for example, combines serializing and posting a request to a url. Using it, posting the action DTO could be reduced to a single line:

```
var data=new {
    action=4,
    device_token="3e8ea119a90ee6d2",
    key = "9475962085b3a1b8c475d52.95782804",
    shop=1,
    language=1
};

var response=await httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync(url,data);
```

Comment: There are a lot of goodies in HttpClient. If you use .NET Core you'll find it contains a *lot* of performance and reliability enhancements. Check Scott Hanselman's [articles](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/HttpClientFactoryForTypedHttpClientInstancesInASPNETCore21.aspx) on the new features

Answer (score 1):

There is a button in Postman that will generate code for the currently defined request. The link is here:
[image]

And this is what the code looks like. You'll need to pull in RestSharp from Nuget
[image]

Comment: THere's no need to use RestClient when .NET already contains HttpClient

Comment: Yeah, you can use HttpClient or the raw socket class to do it. I use this flow when I'm back and forth with Postman shaping the request. Adding a Nuget package isn't a big deal, as you showed above by leveraging Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client

Comment: The difference is asynchronous execution and thread safety. That is a very big deal - the less you block, the less you spinwait, the less CPU you use ==> you need fewer servers for the same load. Since you mentioned sockets, HttpClient in .NET Core 2.1 got a new SocketsHttpClientHandler that reduces allocations by using Span and Pipelines. The result is a huge performance and memory improvement.

Comment: RestSharp offers async methods. Thread blocking doesn't consume CPU. Async/await is very useful and should be used by default when load is a concern but nothing is free, and not every situation requires it