# Getting Post API Call argument as null

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, postman

I am trying to make a post call with very large argument size. But the call is not going through.

**Issue**: When size of parameter is large call is not going through.But in case of small parameter everything is fine that means API is working. I tried to research about `POST` call but couldn't make it work.

**What i Did**
I made a sample api project and tried it to test via postman and project too.

**Postman call**
[image: Postman call]
This is working fine as expected.

**In-Project**
[image]
[image]

If someone is going to point out `rquest.ContentLength = 0;`. This is because param is getting appended to url only. I don't intend it to get appended but
i don't know how to do it and googled too. For small length this is working but say if string length goes to 3000 it fails.

**API Call Initiator**

```
UriBuilder uriBuilder = new UriBuilder(restURL);
var query = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uriBuilder.Query);
query["json"] = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(reportParameterDictionary);
uriBuilder.Query = query.ToString();
restURL = uriBuilder.ToString();
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(restURL);
request.Method = "Post";
request.ContentType = "application/json";
rquest.ContentLength = 0;
using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
{
  StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
  string responseData = reader.ReadToEnd();
  response.Close();
  dynamic obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(responseData);
  if (obj != null)
  {
   printresult = obj.Success;
  }
}
```

**Receiving End**

```
[Route("PrintReport")]
public IHttpActionResult PrintReport(string json)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [POSTing JsonObject With HttpClient From Web API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6117101/posting-jsonobject-with-httpclient-from-web-api)

Comment: @mjwills i tried it, call is going through but value is null at receiving side. 'HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();var content = new StringContent(reportParameterDictionary, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");var result = httpClient.PostAsync(restURL, content).Result;. I tried this and receiving side is `[HttpPost]
        public int Post([FromBody]string value)`

Comment: @mjwills `Request.ContentLength` is giving correct value , let me know how to get the content

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// Create a request using a URL that can receive a post.   
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create ("http://www.contoso.com/PostAccepter.aspx");  
// Set the Method property of the request to POST.  
request.Method = "POST";  
// Create POST data and convert it to a byte array.  
string postData = "This is a test that posts this string to a Web server.";  
byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes (postData);  
// Set the ContentType property of the WebRequest.  
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";  
// Set the ContentLength property of the WebRequest.  
request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;  
// Get the request stream.  
Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream ();  
// Write the data to the request stream.  
dataStream.Write (byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);  
// Close the Stream object.  
dataStream.Close ();  
// Get the response.  
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse ();  
// Display the status.  
Console.WriteLine (((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);  
// Get the stream containing content returned by the server.  
dataStream = response.GetResponseStream ();  
// Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.  
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader (dataStream);  
// Read the content.  
string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd ();  
// Display the content.  
Console.WriteLine (responseFromServer);  
// Clean up the streams.  
reader.Close ();  
dataStream.Close ();  
response.Close ();
```

Follow this [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/how-to-send-data-using-the-webrequest-class) for complete explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use `HttpClient` instead of `HttpWebRequest`?

```
var client = new HttpClient();
var content = new StringContent("YOUR LONG STRING", 
                             System.Text.Encoding.Unicode, 
                             "application/json");            
var task = client.PostAsync(restURL, content);
var str = await task.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```