# How to Send(Post) object Data from c# project to .net core API?

Tags: c#, windows, api, .net-core, post

I want to send an object (DataSet) From the windows application to the .netcore API

something like this
(Windows Application side)

```
public string submitRequest(Dataset request)
        {
            .
            .
            .
            using (client)
            {

                client.Headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
                byte[] result = client.UploadValues(Url, "POST", request);
                return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(result);


            }
        }
```

(.netcore API)

```
public string submitRequest( values)
        {
            // processing values
        }
```

I try to convert to json and try NameValueCollection but no result.

Comment: Don't really now how exactly your whole Client/Server communication looks like but you have to convert the object to binary (by using the `System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter` object for example) and then send it in chunks if it is large or send it in one go if it's small. I'd recommend creating a lightweight TCP Client/Server application and send your raw data via TCP. You can also design your own datagram and make sure that the data being received is valid.

Comment: The post request uses a concept known as Content, which would contain the result byte array.  I don't understand your code as it's different that a straight HttpPost using the HttpClient in C#.  There's plenty of information on this on Microsoft site.  Just remember you can and should send the request in async mode.

Comment: @Max , there is a "Warning - BinaryFormatter is insecure and can't be made secure. For more information, see the BinaryFormatter security guide."  See https://aka.ms/binaryformatter for more information. See also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter?view=net-6.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was simple

**- On the client side**

Create new object :

```
Class1 SentClass1 = new Class1 ();
```

Then serialize the object :

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(SentClass1);
```

Then send the JSON (UploadString) using WebClient

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient()){
       client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType]="application/json";
       response = client.UploadString("ourUrl/SubmitRequest", json);
}
```

On the other hand **- On the Server Side**

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("SubmitRequest")]

public void SubmitRequest(Class2 recievedClass){
      return recievedClass.processing()
}
```

This automatically maps data from (JSON converted from Class1) to Class2 if they have the names of the same attributes if not I can use an auto mapper.

Comment: `WebClient` is not recommended for new development ([as per Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient?view=net-6.0)), instead you should use [HttpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=net-6.0).

Comment: As @risto comment we can use HttpClient instead of WebClient like this

https://stackoverflow.com/a/39414248/12450651